# Equivalent of "FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations.ProcessSignInRequest" in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, ws-federation

First: I'm pretty new to all this authentication/authorization/identification field on back-end side so please forgive me if I speak nonsense.

I'm porting a project from ASP.NET to ASP.NET core.
Right now I'm stuck with porting the identity server.
We use passive WS-Federation to identify users.
Most of the code I could easily port until I met this class:

```
System.IdentityModel.Services.FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations
```

Specifically, I need this method from the above static class:

```
public static SignInResponseMessage ProcessSignInRequest(SignInRequestMessage requestMessage, ClaimsPrincipal principal, SecurityTokenService sts);
```

I couldn't find the equivalent of this class in ASP.NET core or any other suitable replacement.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't exist in ASP.NET Core

Comment: So there is no way to replicate this method logic without writing the code by myself?

Comment: No since it does not exist, you will need to write code.

Comment: Perhaps [this sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.WsFederation) may be useful.

Comment: Try to check [Authenticate users with WS-Federation in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for ws-federation in asp.net core

Comment: @RuardvanElburg, Thank you for your suggestion.
I need a library that supports .NET Core while the one you gave me is for .Net Platform.
But following your link and after a quick search on Git Hub site I could find this repo which may look interesting
https://github.com/ellenfieldn/IdentityServer4.WsFederation?files=1

Comment: @TaoZhou Thank you. I want to implement the back end of the identity server.
The guide you provided shows how to integrate with an existing identity server like the one of Microsoft instead of implementing one.

Comment: @E1adi I have the same problem. Do you solve the issue?